# MongoDb update object if object property is greater

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm new to mongo and could use help with this query.

My objects can look like this.

```
device = {
   stuff:'otherstuff',
   read: {
     moreStuff: 'stuff',
     timestamp: 'some date'
   }
}
```

or this

```
device = {
   stuff:'otherstuff',
}
```

I want to write a query that will update device.read if read doesn't exist or if the new timestamp is greater than the current read.timestamp.  Is there a way to update this in place?  Or do I need to have logic before hand that determines if the timestamp is greater?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: You should check out the $or operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your variables and set variables but this is the base concept

```js
db.collaction.update(
{
  $or:[
  read:{$exists: false},
  "read.timestamp":{$gt:timestamp}
  ]}
,{set:{"read.timestamp":timestamp}}
)
```